# toString() method and recursion

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, tostring

I am creating a class that implements a generic `Set` using a binary search tree. I am implementing my `toString()` method so that it displays a parenthetic expression, but I am having trouble getting it to work. For example, here is a basic binary tree:

[image]

I would want my toString method to output this binary tree as such:

```
(10 (5 (4 () ())   (6 () ()))   (20 (15 () ())   (25 () ())))
```

where `()` signifies an empty tree.

Here is my class with the toString method. Any help is appreciated!

```
// Allow short name access to following classes
import csc143.data_structures.*;

public class MySet<E> implements SimpleSet<E> {

  // the root of the "tree" that structures the set
  private BTNode root;
  // the current number of elements in the set
  private int numElems;

  public MySet() {
    root = null;

    numElems = 0;
  }

  /**
   * Add an element to the set. 
   * 
   * @param e The element to be added to the set.
   * @return  <tt>true</tt> If this operation updated the contents of the set.
   */
  public boolean add(E e) {
    try {
      root = addToSubtree(root, (Comparable) e);
      return true;
    } catch(DuplicateAdded exc) {
      // duplicate trying to be added
      return false;
    }

  }

  // This helper method adds the element "e" to tree rooted at r. Returns
  // (possibly new) tree containing "e", or throws DuplicateAdded exception
  // if "e" already exists in tree.
  private BTNode addToSubtree(BTNode r, Comparable elem)
    throws DuplicateAdded {
    if(r == null) {
      numElems++;
      return new BTNode(elem);
    }

    int compare = elem.compareTo(r.item);
    // element already in tree
    if(compare == 0) {
      throw new DuplicateAdded();
    } else if(compare < 0) {
      r.left = addToSubtree(r.left, elem);
    } else {  // compare > 0
      r.right = addToSubtree(r.right, elem);
    }

    // element has been added
    return r;
  }

  /**
   * Remove all elements from this set.
   */
  public void clear() {
    root = null;

    numElems = 0;
  }

  /**
   * Checks for the existance of the specified value within the set.
   * 
   * @param e The value sought.
   * @return  <tt>true</tt> If the value exists in the set.
   */
  public boolean contains(E e) {
    return subtreeContains(root, (Comparable) e);
  }

  // This helper method returns whether element "elem" is in
  // (sub-)tree with root "r".
  private boolean subtreeContains(BTNode r, Comparable elem) {
    if(r == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      int compare = elem.compareTo(r.item);
      // found element
      if(compare == 0){
        return true;
      } else if(compare < 0) {
        return subtreeContains(r.left, elem);
      } else {  // compare > 0
        return subtreeContains(r.right, elem);
      }

    }

  }

  /**
   * Check for the existance of elements in the set.
   * 
   * @return  <tt>true</tt> If there are no elements in the set.
   */
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
  }

  /**
   * Return the number of elements in the set.
   * 
   * @return The number of elements in the set.
   */
  public int size() {
    return numElems;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a String representation of the contents of the set.
   * 
   * @return  The String representation of the set.
   */
  public String toString() {
    return subtreeToString(root);
  }

  private String subtreeToString(BTNode r) {
    String str = "";
    if(r == null) {
      str += "() ";
      return str;
    } 

    str += "(" + r.item;
    str += subtreeToString(r.left) + 
      subtreeToString(r.right) + ")";

    return str;
  }

  // this inner class creates the node that compose the binary tree structure
  class BTNode<E> {

    /**
     * The item stored in the node.
     */
    public E item;

    /**
     * The node to the left of "this" node.
     */
    public BTNode left;

    /**
     * The node to the right of "this" node.
     */
    public BTNode right;

    /**
     * Constructs the BTNode object (three parameters).
     * 
     * @param item The item to be stored in the node.
     * @param left The node to the left of "this" node.
     * @param right The node to the right of "this" node.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public BTNode(Object item, BTNode left, BTNode right) {
      // bind to references
      this.item = (E) item;
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the BTNode (one parameter).
     * 
     * @param The item to be stored in the node.
     */
    public BTNode(Object item) {
      // call three parameter constructor
      this(item, null, null);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a few issues when I tried running the code, but assuming that all the issues are resolved - the following worked for me:

```
private String subtreeToString(BTNode r) {
    String str = "";
    if(r == null) {
        return str;
    }
    str += r.item;
    str += " (" + subtreeToString(r.left) + ") (" + subtreeToString(r.right) + ")";
    return str;
}
```

Output:

```
10 (5 (4 () ()) (6 () ())) (20 () (25 () ()))
```

(There's also a mistake in the example output that is provided above - a closing bracket should be added after the children of `6`)

Comment: Thanks, just fixed it.

Comment: When I add the integers 1 then 2, I should get `(1 () (2 () ()))`. However, I received `1 (()) (2 (()) (()))`...

Comment: My guess is that when `r` is null you return `()` - hence the double empty brackets. And check out my implementation again - you are not supposed to get an opening bracket before the root. If you want that you should change my implementation from: `str += r.item;` to: `str += "("+r.item; str += " (" + subtreeToString(r.left) + ") (" + subtreeToString(r.right) + "))";`

Comment: I figured it out. You basically had it, just removed a couple of the parentheses and included one before `r.item`. I edited my code with the modifications. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had a question about spacing in my toString method. Right now, for example, I am printing out: `(1 () (2 () (3 () () ))`. However, I am trying to get this instead: `(1 () (2 () (3 () ()))`. Thus, I want no space before a closing parenthesis that is not part of an empty tree's representation: `())`. I have tried many things but cannot seem to get this to work without adding or removing space to an undesired part. I guess I need a way to determine if a closing parenthesis will follow an empty tree representation, so that no space is given. My code above is edited with my latest improvement.

Comment: @user2581779 you can remove the space after `()` in the case where `r==null` - and add instead a space before the bracket on this line: `str += " (" + r.item;`

Comment: I already tried that. The only problem is that there is no space between consecutive empty trees. For the given example, this would result in: `(1 () (2 () (3 ()()))`.

Comment: @user2581779 my solution provides you the exact indentation you asked for, no ?

Comment: Not quite, it does not provide a space between consecutive: `()` `()`, or empty trees.

Comment: @user2581779 yes it does - I copied the output from my IDE at the bottom of the answer. It provides that space because of the `") ("` part

Comment: The `output` that I posted is what I got from running my implementation - so there must be something miss. If `3` has no children it should print (according to my impl.): `3 () ()` not: `3 ()()`

Comment: Your implementation does not have an open parenthesis at the start.

Comment: From what I can tell, your implementation is exactly what I'm looking for except for the missing open parenthesis at the start. By the way, your example above for 3 is correct (mine is incorrect).

Comment: I've been working on it today but with no luck. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: That's an easy one :) all you have to do is create another method that'll call `subtreeToString()` and which will wrap everything with brackets

Comment: Aha! I forgot we were working with a helper method. Again, thanks for your help.